# MVC tkinter model. Switch between frames: add new one on the run

Tags: python, model-view-controller, tkinter, frames

I am following the MVC model that Brian made on the answer to “Switch between two frames in tkinter“. He stacks the frames on top of each other (all are made at the very beginning) and then we just show them at our will.

I try to add another frame on the run. I know it is made (because you get an error before creating it and no error after), but I am cannot show it. What am I missing?
Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3
#import Tkinter as tk     # python 2
#import tkFont as tkfont  # python 2

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def add_new(self):
        ''' Create a new frame on the run '''
        self.frames["PageNew"] = PageNew(parent=tk.Frame(self), controller=self)
        self.frames["PageNew"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")      


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to a New Page ",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageNew"))        
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        button3.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Create a new page and go to the start page",
                       command=self.on_click)
        button.pack()

    def on_click(self):
        self.controller.add_new()
        self.controller.show_frame("StartPage")    


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))   
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the new page",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageNew"))        
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()

class PageNew(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the new page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the parent of your `PageNew`:

`self.frames["PageNew"] = PageNew(parent=tk.Frame(self), controller=self)`

Its parent is a `Frame` you create, but it is not packed inside the GUI so you won't see it, nor its child `PageNew`. In order for `PageNew` to be like the other pages, you need to give it the same parent, which is `container` here.
Since you will need `container` outside of `__init__`, you need to make it an attribute of `SampleApp`, i.e. replace `container = tk.Frame(self)` by `self.container = tk.Frame(self)`.

And now, in `add_new`, you can create your `PageNew` with

`self.frames["PageNew"] = PageNew(parent=self.container, controller=self)`